# Python class inheritance with wx.frame

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, wxpython

I am using python2.7 + wxpython to show some chart data.

I have two class, one(wx class) is manage for wx.frame and another(text decode class) is for parser from file context. I can use self.* to control wx.frame(eg: self.SetMenuBar, self.SetTitle) in wx class, and can I pass this "self" to another class to control the same wx.frame?

Like follow brief code,

```
class CanvasFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size=(550, 350))
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wxc.NamedColour("WHITE"))
        ....
        normal_test_mode_decode(filename, directory)
        ....

class normal_test_mode_decode(CanvasFrame):
    def __init(self, csv_fname, csv_dir):
        ....
        self.SetTitle(os.path.join(csv_dir, csv_fname)) #Error here

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = CanvasFrame(None, "wxPython mathtext demo app")
        ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is error message if I directly use self.SetTitle at another class.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\normal_test_mode_parser\normal_test_mode_parser.py", line 45, in OnOpen
    self.decode = normal_test_mode_decode(filename, directory)
  File "D:\normal_test_mode_parser\normal_test_mode_parser.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.SetTitle(os.path.join(csv_dir, csv_fname))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_windows.py", line 455, in SetTitle
    return _windows_.TopLevelWindow_SetTitle(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: in method 'TopLevelWindow_SetTitle', expected argument 1 of type 'wxTopLevelWindow *'
```

I want to fix this issue because my plan is that a class(CanvasFrame) for wxpython to manage GUI functionality and another class(normal_test_mode_decode) handle data analysis functionality.

thank you!

When run this code, choose file -> open any file, then you see error.

Comment: Please: 1. Post the code within your question (not as a link). 2. Post error messages, etc **as text** within your question (not as links).

Comment: Bill, thanks. I have modified my question and I don't have enough reputation for embed picture.

Comment: I understand. What you need to do is to find out how to copy and paste text from sources like paste.ofcode.org or your terminal screen into SO questions. Since you're using Windows you can right-click in the upper-left corner of the screen labelled c:\python27\python.exe — on the python icon, to get a menu of options that will enable you to cut and paste. You can copy the source code by highlighting the code and then using copy and paste, more or less as you would in any window.

Comment: Bill thanks, I have modified my content. please let me know if anything wrong.

Comment: One problem now is that no-one can run the code you've posted because it's missing lots of lines. I notice too that, although you are using Py2.7 the code at paste.ofcode.org seems to be Py3. Could you please post the minimal code that demonstrates the error you need help with.

Comment: Bill thanks, I have check the code I post on paste.ofcode.org can run with error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few small changes to your code, either to simplify it or to eliminate bugs.

- I replaced more complicated expressions involving `super` with `super()` since you're using Py3 and this makes mistakes less likely to occur.
- In `super().__init__(parent, id=-1, title='something something', size=(550, 350))` I added the literal title. This is probably not what you want to have ultimately but it makes it possible to proceed with development work.
- I changed the lines near `self.content =` to `self.content = self.fp.readline().strip().split(',')` because `line` was undefined. Again, you will probably want to give this more attention.

Comment: Bill thanks, I want to show path on title but it's not. Will it re-create wx.frame when you call super().__init__(parent, -1) in normal_test_mode_decode(CanvasFrame) and not the wx.frame created in CanvasFrame?

Comment: An `__init__` doesn't re-create an object because by the time the `__init__` is called the object is already in existence. The `__init__` merely sets or creates properties within the object. To do what you want put `self.SetTitle(filename)` after the line `self.decode = normal_test_mode_decode(self, filename, directory)`. (You will probably want to change 'something something' as well.

Comment: Do not use paste.ofcode.org in your post, as the links expire after a week. Add the code directly into the question instead